# Azure Data flow taking 7 mins to process 3 records

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The issue i am facing is that Azure Data flow taking around 7 mins to process 3 records

Scenario it have two data source CSV files which is joining and then saving it in the Database but it is taking **7 min some time 8 mins** i don't know why its taking so much time can anyone help me out how to tune it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute your data flow without waiting to provision compute resources, use the pipeline debug feature with the data flow debug session turned on. That will pre-warm Databricks for you and keep it warm for 60 minutes.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792395/azure-data-flow-taking-39-mins-to-copy-only-3000-records

Comment: You may want to leverage the TTL setting in the Azure IR under Data Flow properties (coming soon). Just keep in mind, you'll have to incur a 5-7 min startup time for the cluster at some point for your scheduled pipelines with Data Flow activities.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Mapping Data Flow has a long spin-up time.  This means that those 7 minutes were creating compute resources.  The actual processing time is closer to 3 seconds or less.  There is work underway to alleviate this pain point.

You should be able to verify this in the monitoring section.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792395/azure-data-flow-taking-39-mins-to-copy-only-3000-records